# Basket numeric format

Tags: opayo

I'm developing Sage Pay Server protocol (3.00).
I noticed that in the Integration guideline manual the Amount field must be in UK currency format ("," to separate groups of thousands and "." to indicate the decimal place).
Do I have to use the same format for all numeric values in the Basket? (Quantity, Item value, Item Tax, Item Total, Line Total and number of lines of detail in the basket)

Thank you very much for your help and cooperation

regards

Comment: are you using BasketXML or Basket?

Comment: I'm using Basket standard format whose fields are separated by ":"

Thank you for your help and cooperation

regards

Comment: as per the docs it seems like the amount values format should be the same.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I think to implement it during next week. Thank you for your cooperation.